# Finder Preferences: Unable to hide items on desktop

Tags: macos, finder, desktop

I prefer my desktop to be as empty as possible. So the first thing I do whenever I get a new Mac is hide all items on the desktop (hard disks, external disks, CD's and servers).

On my Mac from work, I am unable to disable "Show these items on the desktop" in Finder Preferences. When clicking the checkbox to hide "hard disks", the checkbox unchecks and checks back on.

[image: Finder Preferences]

What could possibly prevent me from disabling this?

This Mac is managed and configured by our IT department, but I don't wish to contact them for this "non-issue" :)

Thanks

Comment: If that is a bug, I'm sorry that I can't answer the exact question, and I don't even know if you're allowed to add software to a work computer, but, if you can't work out a solution for the problem, get a little app called Desktop Curtain. It sits in the top menu bar, from where you can enable/disable it. It's basically an additional copy layer of your desktop wallpaper image, and you can choose where it appears: Covering all the folders and files of the desktop, or covering all the windows behind the currently active one, etc. You can also assign a shortcut for toggling it on/off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is consistent with your IT department having deployed a configuration profile to your computer that controls your Finder preferences.    If you go into System Preferences and open the "Profiles" preferences you may see the configuration profiles installed on your computer.  I would expect to see one called "MDM Profile" and one or more that configure other aspects of your computer, such as the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

As this is abnormal behavior and you say that the Mac is configured and managed by your IT Department, I would say that you *have* contact them, because it's most likely their doing....

Answer (score -1):

Try Path Finder. But first, disable SIP in recovery terminal. (csrutil disable) Then try other things.

Comment: How does this solve the issue described in the question? And would this work on a Mac which is managed/configured by an IT department?